# DetailView Show Model With Boolean Property Set to True

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, detailview

I am creating a Django web app and am trying to set a page model to be the homepage (page at root directory).

There can only be one homepage model, and homepages are set via setting the the `homepage` variable to true. Settings one true, will set the previous homepage to false.

```
# models.py
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    homepage = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.homepage:
            return super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        with transaction.atomic():
            Page.objects.filter(
                homepage=True).update(homepage=False)
            return super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        # return self.title + '   |   ' + str(self.author)
        return self.title
```

```
# views.py
class HomePage(DetailView):
    model = Page.objects.filter(homepage=True)
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

In my views.py script, I am trying to get the model which has `homepage = True` and displaying it as a DetailView.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', HomePage.as_view(), name="home"),
    ...
]
```

```
<!-- home.html -->
<h1>Home</h1>

{{ page.body }}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError at /
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is here:

```
# views.py
class HomePage(DetailView):
    model = Page.objects.filter(homepage=True)
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

in the model field you have to pass a Model, if you want to change the context data by passing a filtered queryset you have to do it via the [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method

```
# views.py
class HomePage(DetailView):
    model = Page
    template_name = 'home.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Page.objects.filter(homepage=True)
```

Comment: I've modified the HomePage class as you've suggested, now I'm getting a different error: ```Generic detail view HomePage must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.```. How do I fix this?

Comment: I changed ```get_queryset(self)``` to ```get_object(self)```. Now the page.html page shows, but the ```{{ page.body }}``` is not shown, only the h1 tags are being rendered on to the screen

Comment: Instead of UpdateView try using TemplateView. It doesn't have any requirements in terms of pk or urlconf

Comment: With the ```get_queryset(self)``` method and using ```TemplateView``` the home.html page is showing but the ```{{ home.body }}``` is not being rendered, how do I fix this?

Comment: Unless you changed the context_object_name field in the TemplateView you will render the field with {{ object.body }}. If you want to keep {{ home.body }} write in your view: context_object_name = "home"